# Is there any similar function in python like robocopy with retry options?

Tags: python, robocopy, file-copying

Currently i'm using shutil.copyfileobj method to copy a file to a destination folder. The destination folder is a networkshare folder. Sometimes the folder is not reachable, when the pc restarts. I know that we can specify a number of retries on failed copies with robocopy. Unfortunately this is not possible in python. Is there something similiar to robocopy in python? Or how can i do it in python with the shuthil.copyfileobj?

Comment: Handle the exception and repeat until it succeeds or you run out of retries. Which part of that are you having trouble with? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: If you need Robocopy's more sophisticated recovery features, consider using `subprocess` to call out to Robocopy. Otherwise you will end up rewriting it.

Comment: i thought there is maybe a python librarary which gives us a more powerful copymethod :) I think i'll handle the exception and repeat it. Thanks for the suggestions